# summernote point cursor at the end of the HTML inserted

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote, cursor-position

what I'm trying to do is selected text on the page and adding that text as a quote in the text-editor i.e. summernote.

It works pretty well, I'm using following code to achieve the same

```
$pby = 'someone';
$selected_txt = $.trim(window.getSelection().toString());
$quote_htm = '<blockquote class="hero"><small><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> originally posted by <strong>'+$pby+'</strong></small><em>'+$selected_txt+'</em></blockquote><br /><p></p>';
```

to insert the above quote into summernote text-editor I'm using following code

```
$existing_htm = $("#forum_reply_descr").summernote("code");
$html = ($existing_htm == '<p><br></p>' ? '' : $existing_htm)+$quote_htm;
$("#forum_reply_descr").summernote("code", $html);
$("#forum_reply_descr").summernote({focus: true});
```

this also works well but the cursor position remain at the beginning of the text, I want to position the cursor at the end of the html but I couldn't find anything to programmatically move the cursor to the very end!

Is there a way we can move the cursor using Summernote API or any hack to achieve the same result? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement this on your project

```
$('#some_id').focus(function(){
  var input1 = this;
  setTimeout(function(){ input1.selectionStart = input1.selectionEnd = 10000; }, 0);
});


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='some_id' type='text' value='input message here with cursor at the end'>
```